# Data type mismatch in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, avro

I created an external table in hive where divcd is string datatype. The data is stored in avro format. Below is the issue I face while querying

```
WHERE divcd = ‘20’ 

However, this returned no rows.  When I tried:

WHERE divcd = 20

returned rows.
```

I'm unable to sort it out. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Looks the datatype is not string.  Check the avro format.

Comment: In .avsc file it is in string data type